# How do I enable my innodb

Tags: 10.04, server, mysql

I need to enable innodb on my ubuntu server 10.04 and having tons of problems, I have tried posting questions everywhere and I have no answers....i tried this

```
show variables like "%innodb%";
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| have_innodb           | NO    |
| ignore_builtin_innodb | OFF   |
+-----------------------+-------+
```

so it seems like it is not installed or something but i keep reading its installed by default

```
show engines;
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| ARCHIVE    | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I dont see it in the output and when trying to install Social Engine I get this:

[image: screen]

Comment: How did you install MySQL?

Comment: I used linode server with preconfigured lamp "Originally created using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and 'LAMP Stack' StackScript at revision 160"

Comment: in a virtual machine with 10.04.2 installed `sudo tasksel install lamp-server` MySQL installs with InnoDB engine available. This might be something you have to take up with Linode Support

Comment: Let us know if it was a problem with Linode - if not we can try to help you troubleshoot further :)

Answer (score 6):

here is the solution

enabling the following two InnoDB directives in your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file appears to have resolved this issue:

```
default-storage-engine=innodb
default-table-type=innodb
```

When restarting your MySQL server, there appears to have been some lingering processes so the `mysqld.sock` file wasn't being created correctly. As you saw in Lish, I forcefully killed the lingering processes using the `kill` command, and then restarted MySQL normally with `service mysql start` which allowed the `mysqld.sock` file to be created.